# Can a single ascx page use multiple codefile which are partial classes

Tags: c#, ascx

Can we link up two partial classes to a single ascx page.

I have gone through some of the links but could not find a suitable solution for the same.
Suppose for example I am having files such as

Collection.ascx.cs and Collection.Search.cs
with Collection.ascx

I am having events like button click event, could it be placed in the partial class, as doing so would make the method unavailable.
My intention is to handle button click events and the dropdown change events in the partial class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, In WebApplication, It is a default nature for a .aspx (web page) and .ascx (user control).

These are by default comes with two .cs files, separating code in partial classes (filename.aspx.designer.cs and filename.aspx.cs with same partial class)

You can also add more .cs files to extend these partial class definition.

But in website, it will not work, for aspx or ascx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the C# compiler rules for partial classes don't change because its ASP.NET. Just make sure your namespace and class name matches, the source file doesn't have to be a child of the `ascx` file in the Solution Explorer, but if you really want it to you can edit the project file and add the appropriate depends-on xml segment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer locates at default.aspx 1st line:

```
Language="C#" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" ...
```

will set every partial class working.

Instead,

```
Language="C#" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" ...
```

will lead partial class to wrong.

However, in vs2017 old-style-webForm you can only use CodeFile, so you have to try another way: just create a file ..\WebF8\App_Code\Class3.cs with content :

```
     public static class Class3 {
            public static int gg3=33;
     }
```

then you can see Class3.gg3 in default.aspx.cs correctly.
Be careful, this Class3.cs file must be in \App_Code folder.